# Convert R to wide format with arrangement depending on value in column

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot

I have got a table containing data from various samples ("sample1" etc) with which several types measurement (A to C) were made. Every measurement gave 3 values: concentration, maximum and minimum.

```
my.sample <- c("sample1", "sample1", "sample2", "sample2", "sample3")
type <- c("A", "B", "A", "C", "C")
concentration <- c(12, 5, 7, 10, 14)
max <- c(13, 6, 7, 11, 15)
min <- c(11, 4, 6, 9, 13)

mydata <- data.frame(my.sample, type, concentration, max, min)

> mydata
  my.sample type concentration max min
1   sample1    A            12  13  11
2   sample1    B             5   6   4
3   sample2    A             7   7   6
4   sample2    C            10  11   9
5   sample3    C            14  15  13
```

I'd like to convert this data to a new table where I only have one row per sample. This means creating 3 columns (concentration, max, min) for every measurement type, with the type of measurement indicated in the column. Missing values should be defined as `NA`. Here's an example of the result I'd like to obtain:

```
A_concentration <- c(12, 7, NA)
A_max <- c(13, 7, NA)
A_min <- c(11, 6, NA)

B_concentration <- c(5, NA, NA)
B_max <- c(6, NA, NA)
B_min <- c(4, NA, NA)

C_concentration <- c(NA, 10, 14)
C_max <- c(NA, 11, 15)
C_min <- c(NA, 9, 13)

mydata.new <- data.frame(my.sample.new, A_concentration, A_max, A_min, B_concentration, B_max, B_min, C_concentration, C_max, C_min)

> mydata.new
  my.sample.new A_concentration A_max A_min B_concentration B_max B_min
1       sample1              12    13    11               5     6     4
2       sample2               7     7     6              NA    NA    NA
3       sample3              NA    NA    NA              NA    NA    NA
  C_concentration C_max C_min
1              NA    NA    NA
2              10    11     9
3              14    15    13
```

Is there a method to widen data based on a condition and include a value (here: from  `type` ) in the column name? I have got many more types in my real dataset, so it should ideally be generalisable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = my.sample, names_from = type, values_from = c(concentration, max, min), names_glue = "{type}_{.value}") %>% 
  select(my.sample, starts_with("A"), starts_with("B"), starts_with("C"))
```

This gives us:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 10
  my.sample A_concentration B_concentration C_concentration A_max B_max C_max A_min B_min C_min
  <chr>               <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 sample1                12               5              NA    13     6    NA    11     4    NA
2 sample2                 7              NA              10     7    NA    11     6    NA     9
3 sample3                NA              NA              14    NA    NA    15    NA    NA    13
```

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks! How do I put the type values first in the column names (e.g. A_concentration etc)?

Comment: @Nereus np! updated the post. You can use `names_glue`